# Scrolling with mouseover event

Tags: jquery, events, mouseover, jscrollpane

I am using jScrollPane to scroll a div.  Currently the default is to click the up and down arrows to scroll the pane.  But, I would like to use mouseover instead.  I have looked at the code but it is not entirely obvious how one would do this.

Has anyone done this before?  Ideas?

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/scripts/jScrollPane.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

> Usage
>
> Just include the following files in
>   the head of your page:
>
> ```
> * jQuery (I'm using 1.2.6 here)
> * the mouse wheel plugin (if you want mouse wheel support)
> * the jQEm plugin (if you want your scroll panes to automagically resize when the user changes text size)
> * jScrollPane.js
> * jScrollPane.css
> ```

Look at the examples on the page to see how it's done.

Edit: Sorry I misread your post, you to use the mouseover event instead.

What you could do is:

Bind a `mouseover` event handler for the up and down buttons, and make them invoke `$(this).click();`

Comment: Yes, I know how to initialize it, but I want to use mouseover.  I will look into your suggestion.